# Barcode line overlay scanner in flutter package mobile_scanner: ^2.1.0

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm using  package mobile_scanner in my flutter application, and it works fine, it opens the camera in full screen and scans QR/Barcode in any place on the screen. I want to add a specific detection area on the screen with a camera full view. how can I achieve this.

I researched and found this package does not  have that feature , what can be the solution
Note: I don't like to replace this package with other i.e I must stay in this package.

What I am doing is this:

```
body: Stack(
  children: [
    MobileScanner(
        allowDuplicates: false,
        controller: cameraController,
        onDetect: (qrcode, args) {
          if (qrcode.rawValue == null) {
            debugPrint('Failed to scan Barcode');
          } else {
            final String code = qrcode.rawValue!;
            Get.off(QrInfo(codeInfo: code), binding: QrCodeBinding());

            debugPrint('Qr found! $code');
          }
        }),
    Center(
        child: Image.asset(
      'assets/qrFrame.png',
      scale: 0.25,
          color: Colors.red,
    )),
  ],
));
```